# line 8: [: N: integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

I'm receiving the error **line 8: [: N: integer expression expected**. I have tried removing the **" "** in the **$userManuf** and changing **=** to **==** and I still receive the error. What should I do? Thanks

```
function manuf {
 echo -n "Manufacturer: " ; read userManuf
 varManuf=$(mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT count(id) FROM manufacturers;")
 countManuf=$(echo $varManuf | awk '{print $2}')

 if [ $userManuf -ne 0 ] && [ $userManuf -le $countManuf ]; then
    assetModelManuf=$userManuf
 elif [ "$userManuf" = "n" ] || [ "$userManuf" = "N" ]; then
    echo -n "Type new manufacturer name: " ; read userNewManuf
    assetModelManuf=$userNewManuf
 else    echo "Try again!" && manuf
 fi
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what language this is. Use tags.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, its bash script and I'm new to this. Yes I read about writing conditional expressions and also comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring when `$userManuf` expands to `N`, but you try to use it as an operand with the *integer* operator `-ne`. The simplest fix would be to verify that it has a numerical value first (then use an arithmetic statement to simplify the comparison):

```
if [[ $userManuf =~ [0-9]+ ]] && (( 0 < userManuf && userManuf <= countManuf )); then
    assetModelManuf=$userManuf
elif [[ $userManuf = [nN] ]]; then
    read -p "Type new manufacturer name: " assetModelManuf
else
    echo "Try again!" && manuf
fi
```

You probably also want to use a `while` loop instead of calling `manuf` recursively. I'll leave that as an exercise (or a future question, if necessary).

Comment: Thank you so much @chepner, I will try to study **do while** loop for awhile. Can you please tell the difference of using **[** / **(** and **[[** / **((** or link a site?. Thank you!

Comment: @PauloBernardo BashFAQ an article on [test commands (including `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031), and another on [shell arithmetic (including `(( ))`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).